# How do I insert data into remote MongoDB in meteorjs? How do I know if I'm connected to the remote MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, amazon-ec2

I'm a newbie in MongoDB and MeteorJS. I'm trying connect my meteor app to a remote mongodb. I have a mongodb setup on ec2. Here's my mongod.conf:

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
port = 27000
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
auth=true
```

I tried to connect my meteor app on my laptop to the server. So I did this:

```
#in meteor app folder
#in terminal
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://<admin>:<pwd>@<ec2-address>.compute.amazonaws.com:27000/meteor
```

In my meteor app folder, I have three files; connectmongo.html, connnectmongo.js and connectmongo.css

My connectmongo.js looks like this:

```
Test = new Mongo.Collection('test');
```

Then, I ran the meteor command in the terminal and I got the following errors:

```
skaxwng@xps13:~/meteor/conmongo$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/meteor/conmongo ]]]]]                 

=> Started proxy.                             
W20150502-10:38:10.043(-5)? (STDERR)          
W20150502-10:38:10.046(-5)? (STDERR)   /home/skaxwng/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
W20150502-10:38:10.046(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150502-10:38:10.046(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150502-10:38:10.047(-5)? (STDERR) [object Object]
W20150502-10:38:10.047(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Future.wait (/home/skaxwng/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
W20150502-10:38:10.047(-5)? (STDERR)     at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:213:1)
W20150502-10:38:10.047(-5)? (STDERR)     at new      MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:1)
W20150502-10:38:10.047(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:1)
W20150502-10:38:10.047(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750:1)
W20150502-10:38:10.048(-5)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:98:1)
W20150502-10:38:10.048(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/conmongo.js:27:8
W20150502-10:38:10.048(-5)? (STDERR)     at app/conmongo.js:29:3
W20150502-10:38:10.048(-5)? (STDERR)     at /home/skaxwng/meteor/conmongo/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150502-10:38:10.048(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

I don't know if my app is connected to mongo or not. I don't any errors on that.

Can someone please help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: Did you open port 2700 in your AWS-EC2 security section ?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to open up the port. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the port `27000` is opened in the AWS security rules, and then you can use `mongo hostname:port/database -u username -p password` command to verify the `MONGO_URL`.